# Get (none):~ when logging in

Tags: ssh, opensuse

I have an OpenSUSE server, I have disable login by password and only allow authorized_keys to log in. However, when I restart my server, I got the weird terminal

(none):~ #

But things are still ok so far. So I dont know if it is a big problem or not ?

Comment: Due to '#' in prompt, your user is root. Seems like something happened with your .$(SHELL)rc. Default shell is bash, so if you didn't change it, check if /root/.bashrc is readable and is ok. You can check your current shell with `echo $SHELL` command.

Comment: ...and what is your prompt *supposed* to be? (`echo $PS1`)

Comment: are you in single user mode?  Sounds like you might be.  what does "/sbin/runlevel" return?  does "cat /proc/cmdline" end with "single"?  what does "whoami" return?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 root root   73 Dec  7 23:56 .bashrc  
echo $SHELL  
/bin/bash`  

My prompt supposed to be: li62-392:~ #

runlevel
N 3

cat /proc/cmdline
root=/dev/xvda xencons=tty console=tty1 console=hvc0 nosep nodevfs ramdisk_size=32768 ip_conntrack.hashsize=8192 nf_conntrack.hashsize=8192 ro  devtmpfs.mount=1

whoami
root

Thank all for your comments

Comment: Sorry I cant make the comment to be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings of "use pam" and "use login" in your sshd-configuration. It seems that during ssh-login your environment is not set up correctly.

Either that - or you did not set your hostname properly.